# Combining query_string with bool filters in Elasticsearch 2.x

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to do a query combining query_string and bool filters. something like combining two bellow:

1.

```
    'query': {
        'query_string': {
             'query': "Blah Blah",
         }
    },
```

2.

```
 'query': {
    'bool': {
        'must': [
             {
                  'terms': {
                       'newsline': ['blah']
                  }
             }
        ]
    }
 }
```

but by combining two query i have error:

```
'failed to parse search source. expected field name but got [START_OBJECT]'
```

This is combine query:

```
    'query': {
        'query_string': {
             'query': "Blah Blah",
         },
         'bool': {
             'must': [
                  {
                    'terms': {
                        'newsline': ['blah']
                      }
                  }
             ]
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there! `query_string` simply needs to go inside the `bool/must` as well:

```
'query': {
     'bool': {
         'must': [
              {
                'query_string': {
                    'query': "Blah Blah",
                }
              },
              {
                'terms': {
                    'newsline': ['blah']
                  }
              }
         ]
    }
},
```